# Tiling the hyperbolic plane.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tiling, tessellations

I found this theorem online and I have no idea how to prove it. I can't find a proof anywhere; if anyone knows one that would be great.

Theorem 6.10

Let $D$ be a hyperbolic triangle with angles $\frac{\pi}{l}, \frac{\pi}{m}$ and $\frac{\pi}{n}$. Then the triangles obtained by inverting (or reflecting) $\triangle$ in each of its sides and then inverting each of the images in each of its sides, and so on indefinitely, cover the hyperbolic plane without gaps or improper overlaps.

Comment: One approach could be starting with a tiling of Euclidean space tiled by triangles and then applying a transform that converts everything to hyperbolic space.

Comment: Why don't you type the four little lines of the theorem ?

Comment: @JeanMarie look like regular size lines to me

Comment: I appeciate the humor of your answer. It remains that an image is not searchable while a text is, and it takes only some minutes to type such a text...

Comment: @JeanMarie you win

Comment: It is a standard result indeed, a consequence of the fundamental polygon theorem.

Comment: About Poincaré's polygon theorem, see this detailed [article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/MotzStoreyTesselations.pdf).

Comment: Do you know that such a paving is easy to do with geogebra ?

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you I've found the article very helpful :)